# Excel nested IF - multiple conditions in a single formula

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to assign levels of recommendation based on certain values in cell C.

However, I am not sure why this IFS statement is returning with errors.

=IFS(C2< =2.00, “Do Not Recommend”, C2 <=3.33, “Do Not Recommend/Borderline”, C2 <=3.34, “Recommend”, C2=>3.78, “Strongly Recommend”)

Lastly: 
If I wanted to assign the cell above TWO possible final recommendations, would it be an IF OR statement. For example... IF a candidate is "Do not Recommend" (Cell C3), they can be rejected **or** placed on hold. How would I reflect that in the code.

Comment: You need to **nest** the ifs.

Comment: so what is supposed to happen if C2 between 3.34 and 3.78?

Answer (score 0):

`IFS` isn't a defined function in Excel.

What you're looking for is called **Nested Ifs**. You need to use the structure of the `IF` formula: `=IF(condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])` and use the different combinations of conditions to match your goal.

So, for example, if I want to check if the value in cell `A1` is bigger than 3, between 2 and 3 or smaller than 2, I'll write:

```
=IF(A1>3, "A1>3", IF(A1>2, "2<A1<3", "A1<2"))
                  ^ Here starts the 'false' position of (A1>3)
```